# The right function requires 2 argument(s)

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

I am trying to increment an nvarchar value as shown below

```
SELECT 'A' + RIGHT('000', CAST((MAX(UserID) + 1) as nvarchar(50)), 3) FROM users
```

I'm getting the following error:

***`The right function requires 2 argument(s)`***

Can anyone say me what does this error mean and how do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Like the error message says, the RIGHT() function takes in 2 arguments. You are passing in 3 arguments:

```
'000'
CAST((MAX(UserID) + 1) as nvarchar(50))
3
```

Perhaps you want to do something like this instead, and only pass in two arguments?

```
SELECT 'A' + RIGHT('000' + CAST((MAX(UserID) + 1) as nvarchar(50)), 3) FROM users
```

Comment: @Marty-Thanks for the quick response..Now it gives me error as Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'A001' to data type int.

Comment: @coder 'A001' naturally cannot be converted to `int`

Comment: @nathan742-So how do I modify it?

Comment: Where is the error coming from? The code I posted shouldn't generate that error.